# How to store the actual user logged into my database and display it as a created by field for my CRUD?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have this code in my controller:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $request->get('nombre');
    $request->get('correo');
    $request->get('creado_por');
    $creado_por = Auth::user()->id;

    $request->validate([
        'creado_por' => 'string'
    ]);

    return ComprasNotificacionCancelacion::create([
        'nombre' => request('nombre'),
        'correo' => request('correo')
    ]);
}
```

This is the model:

```
protected $table = 'compras_notificacion_cancelacions';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $fillable = [
    'nombre',
    'correo',
    'creado_por'
];

protected $dates = [
    'fecha_creacion',
    'fecha_modificacion'
];
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: brother question is not clear. You want to add created by field to ComprasNotificacionCancelacion model?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but what you are trying to do is add logged in user as the creado_por here is how you can achieve that.

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'creado_por' => 'string'
    ]);

    //here you can use either Auth()->user()->id or $request->user()->id
    return ComprasNotificacionCancelacion::create([
        'nombre' => $request->nombre,
        'correo' => $request->correo,
        'creado_por' => $request->user()->id
    ]);
}
```

additionally here are somethings you could improve. You can access same Auth()->user() from $request like $request->user().
You don't need the below codes.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$request->get('nombre');
$request->get('correo');
$request->get('creado_por');
$creado_por = Auth::user()->id;
```

and if using id as id no need to mention it

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I store the author of an entry is that I have a `created_by` column in the database and I make sure that contains the right ID inside the model. Here's a trait I use, that I call `CreatedByTrait.php` and use it on the models that need it:

```php
<?php namespace App\Models\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait CreatedByTrait {

    /**
     * Stores the user id at each create & update.
     */
    public function save(array $options = [])
    {

        if (\Auth::check())
        {
            if (!isset($this->created_by) || $this->created_by=='') {
                $this->created_by = \Auth::user()->id;
            }
        }

        parent::save();
    }


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'created_by');
    }
}
```